# Example of a non-zero infinitely differentiable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is $0$ on an open interval

Tags: analysis

I want to know an example of an infinitely differentiable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is $0$ on an open interval (say) $(0,1)$ but not trivial (I.e. not zero everywhere).

I know this is not possible for an analytic functions, by the identity principle, but the usual examples of non-analytic smooth functions do not work here.

Comment: You make take $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The usual suspect $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2} &\text{if } x>0\\
0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
would do the trick.

Comment: Make that $e^{-1/x^2}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks. Typos always have the better of me.

Comment: Any particular reason to choose $e^{-1/x^2}$ instead of $e^{-1/x}$? Asking because I see the former example everywhere even while the latter works.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir For constructions, I assume the fact that $x^2$ is even can be useful (to use a bump function "from the left" instead of "from the right"). Not really sure if there's anything more.

Comment: @ClementC. I don't understand your point about bump functions -- surely the $f(x)f(1-x)$ construction works just as well in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x):=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}& x>0\\ 0& x\le0\end{cases}$